# How do I edit opcodes or write memory or edit bytes in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse-engineering, memory-editing

I am memory editing a game called Assault Cube which can be found at: http://assault.cubers.net/

I'm not sure how to describe it, so I've made a video of me doing it: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=SS1swxQIbDI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SS1swxQIbDI)

Notice that my ammo goes down before the edit. After the edit, the ammo stays constant. Basically, at 0x45B75F, I need to insert two NOPs.

I've found the following on the internet:

1.

```
BYTE NewBytes[] = { 0xXX, 0xXX, 0xXX, 0xXX, 0xXX };
*(PBYTE)0xXXXXXXXX[0] = NewBytes;
```

So I tried doing:

```
BYTE NewBytes[] = { 0x90, 0x90 };
*(PBYTE)0x45B75F[0] = NewBytes;
```

But I get this error: `error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type`

2.

```
DWORD origProtect;
VirtualProtect( ( void* )0x77D142CF, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &origProtect );
memcpy( ( void* )0x77D142CF, "\x8B\xFF\x55\x8B\xEC", 5 );
VirtualProtect( ( void* )0x77D142CF, 5, origProtect, NULL );
```

I would prefer to not use memcpy or any method.

3.

```
char val = 0x48;
BOOL success = WriteProcessMemory(target, 0x10134CE0, &val, 1, NULL);
```

Again, I would prefer to not use a method.

4.

```
uint8_t* code = (uint8_t*)0x45B75F;
*code = 0x90;
```

The above gives me these errors:

```
error C2065: 'uint8_t' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'code' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'uint8_t' : undeclared identifier
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2065: 'code' : undeclared identifier
```

5.

```
*(char*)0x45B75F = 0x90;
```

This results in a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
You've double-dereferenced here. What you want is:

```
*((BYTE *) (0x45B75F + 0)) = NewBytes[0];
*((BYTE *) (0x45B75F + 1)) = NewBytes[1];
```

When overwriting code, you need to ensure that execution is not running the code that you're overwriting. Otherwise, you might introduce a race condition where you accidentally introduce invalid or undesired instructions for a short period of time. You might look into atomic operations (where applicable) for performing your binary rewriting.

2.
Your aversion to `memcpy` here seems questionable. It is possible that the compiler will optimise the `memcpy` into a doubleword-`MOV`, followed by a single byte `MOV`. You can force this issue by encoding your 5 bytes into one 32-bit integer, and a single byte. Alternatively, you can write 5 consecutive writes to memory, and the compiler might automatically combine them. For example:

```
code[0] = byte0;
code[1] = byte1;
etc.
```

3.
Why do you want to avoid using this function? I am unfamiliar with windows, but this appears to be a standard way to write to another process's memory.

4.
`uint8_t` is defined in `stdint.h` C99 standard library header; you must include it. The error about `code` not being declared is a side-effect of the former error with `uint8_t`.

5.
That is not unreasonable. You're injecting a `NOP` into an assumed well-defined address, with no regard to what you're overwriting. Take this simple example:

Suppose I have an instruction in memory call `I1`, and it takes up two bytes: `[I1_0, I1_1]`. Right now, what you're doing is potentially overwriting one of those bytes with a `NOP`, with no regard as to whether the surrounding bytes will remain valid as instructions, e.g. `[0x90, I1_1]` or `[I1_0, 0x90]`. If `I1_0` or `I1_1` alone are invalid opcode sequences, then of course the program will crash!

Another reason why this might not work is that it's common (at least on Mac and Linux) for a debugger (in your case, OllyDbg) to lay out the address space of the process being debugged in a different way than the OS will when the process is run natively. That means that an address like `0x45B75F` might be meaningful in the debugger but meaningless when trying to operate on the memory of a native process.

A third reason why this might not work is that the write to memory (without more information from you) appears to be operating on the memory of your process and not the memory of another process (unless that is what you are trying to do). If that memory address is even mapped, it still might not be available for writing (due to page protection).

Comment: I am using DLL injection, so I am writing in the memory of the game's process. Which approach would you recommend out of the five? The reason why I wanted to avoid memcpy or WriteProcessMemory was because I wanted to understand how the memory was being edited.

Comment: First, figure out how many bytes you need to overwrite. You can do this by subtracting two addresses in your debugger: the next instruction address and the address of the instruction to be overwritten. Then find a method to write that many NOPs (e.g. memcpy). Then find a reliable way to find the place where you need to write. For example, if the instruction to be overwritten is at offset X of the start of the binary, then use a tool to get the base address of the text section of the binary, add X, and overwrite at that point.